# Translation of Pichifkes

Tags: translation, story-identification, hashgacha-pratit

Rav [Henoch Teller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoch_Teller) has a book titled [Pichifkes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/096147727X) (most of which can be read [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=uxavJBdf0oQC&pg=PA45&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)) on stories of Divine Providence. What does "Pichifkes" mean?

Comment: Commonly translated as “knickknacks”, though means “in/with all its details”.

Answer (score 1):

[Lehmans](https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/pichifkes.html) gives the translation of the book's web site. pichifkes is curios in Yiddish

Comment: Curios means a rare, unusual, or intriguing object.

Comment: @GershonGold which is why he gave it that title